# Jenkins multi configuration project doesn't show custom plugin in build step?

Tags: jenkins

I have written a custom plugin for Jenkins and it works like a charm with a free-style project. However, when I create a new multi configuration project, the plugin is not there anymore in the "build step combobox".

Anyone got experience with this? Are there any requirements for a plugin to be compatible with the multi configuration project?

Looks a bit as:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12036

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to follow [this note](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin)?

> **Missing builder**
>   If you're not able to add the builder of your choice within a conditional build step (because it's not available within the dropdown), then this is likely because the builder does not provide a @DataBoundConstructor constructor and/or the Descriptor does not extend hudson.tasks.BuildStepDescriptor. For non programmers: the plugin you would like to use does not yet follow the newest Jenkins coding guidelines. Without this, the conditional buildstep plugin is not able to work with it.

If you've got the descriptor, then check [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Create+a+new+Plugin+with+a+custom+build+Step)

> As we are writting a descriptor for a Builder, we extend BuildStepDecriptor for convenience. We then have to implement two methods :
>    ***isApplicable*** will be used to ask the descriptor if the component it manages can be used by the current project. **You may want your plugin to apply only to FreeStyle projects but not Maven or Matrix ones**.
>    ***getDisplayName*** allow us to declare the label used in the Build Steps select box when user will configure the job. Remember that when we will talk about internationalization bellow

So, your descriptor should look like

```
@Extension
public static class Descriptor extends BuildStepDescriptor<Builder> {

    @Override
    public boolean isApplicable(Class<? extends AbstractProject> jobType) {
        return hudson.model.FreeStyleProject.class.isAssignableFrom(jobType)
            || hudson.matrix.MatrixProject.class.isAssignableFrom(jobType);
    }
```

See [this](http://javaadventure.blogspot.ru/2008/06/writing-hudson-plugin-part-7-putting-it.html) and [this one](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Create+a+new+Plugin+with+a+custom+build+Step) for example.

Comment: This is the correct answer! Thank you so much! I overlooked the note.